# Send token in header using volley library in android

Tags: android, http, get, request, android-volley

I'm trying to send Get request to server using volley  library in android but it failed to get response but when I send the same request from Postman it success to get response. I must to send token parameter in header to get the response. what is the problem although I add token in the request in java code but it failed to get response ?

Android Java code

```
public static void sendPostRequest(Context context, String token, HashMap<String, String> parameters)
{
    try {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://api.palcharge.com/WS/listProviders?username=api",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("Response", response);
                        // handle response
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Toasty.warning(SelectBlog.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("token", token);
                return params;
            }
        };


        VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        Log.d("Request", stringRequest.getHeaders().toString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Snapshot from Postman when I send request

[image: This success request using Postman]

Answer (score 0):

@Override

```
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            return params;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.